# Detectar cambio en un CheckBox dentro de una TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Tengo una lista observable cuyos elementos se muestran en una tabla una de cuyas columnas es un `CheckBox` que puede modificarse por el usuario pulsando con el ratón sobre ellos. Quiero que cuando estos `CheckBox` cambien se me notifique para almacenar esos cambios en una base de datos.

La columna de los `CheckBox` es esta:

```
TableColumn<Person, Boolean> acceptedCol = new TableColumn<>("Accepted");
acceptedCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("accepted"));
acceptedCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) -> {
    CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
    cell.getStyleClass().add("okGrasa");
    cell.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);            
    return cell;
    });
```

La lista está formada por objetos de la clase `Person`:

```
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private BooleanProperty accepted;

    public Person(String name, boolean accepted) {
        this.name = name;    
        this.accepted = new SimpleBooleanProperty(accepted);
    }  
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }   
    public BooleanProperty acceptedProperty() {
        return accepted;
    }
    public boolean isAccepted() {
        return acceptedProperty().get();
    }
}
```

He rellenado la tabla con la lista:

```
ObservableList<Person> list = getPersonList();
TableView<Person> table = new TableView<>();
table.setItems(list);
```

Y he probado esto:

```
list.addListener(new ListChangeListener() { 
    @Override
    public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change c) { 
        System.out.println ("Ha habido un cambio");
    }
});
```

Pero sólo me detecta cambios en la lista observable pero no detecta la edición de cada uno de los elementos que la integran ¿Por qué?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La clase 'Person' es correcta no así la CellFactory que utilizas.

Aquí tienes un programa funcional con las correcciones oportunas. Falta implementar la hoja de estilo en el fichero "HojaDeEstilo.css" que tienes que colocar en la misma carpeta que este código con una etiqueta ". miClaseEstiloPersonal".
Asegúrate que tengas la versión 9 de Java JDK instalada ya que en versiones anteriores este código da problemas.
(Basado en las respuestas de la versión inglesa de StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25210690/checkboxtablecell-changelistener-not-working
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671132/javafx-checkboxtablecell-get-actionevent-when-user-check-a-checkbox

```
public class CheckBoxTableCellTest extends Application {

  TableView<Person> tabla  = new TableView<>();     
  ObservableList<Person> lista ;

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    TableColumn<Person, Boolean> acceptedCol = new TableColumn<>("Aceptado");
    List<Person> items = Arrays.asList(new Person());
    lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList(new Person());

    tabla.setItems(this.lista);
    tabla.getColumns().addAll(acceptedCol);

    acceptedCol o.setEditable(true);
    tabla.setEditable(true);

    acceptedCol.setCellFactory((TableColumn<Person, Boolean> p) -> {
        final CheckBoxTableCell<Person, Boolean> cell = new CheckBoxTableCell<>();
        final BooleanProperty selected = new SimpleBooleanProperty();
        cell.setSelectedStateCallback((Integer index) -> lista.get(index).propiedadAceptado());        
        cell.getStyleClass().add("okGrasa");           
        return cell;
    });               

    lista = FXCollections.observableArrayList((Person param) -> new Observable[]{param.propiedadAceptado()});    
    lista.addListener((Observable o) -> {
        System.out.println("Cambia el checkBox");    
    });

    lista.addAll(items); 
    BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
    root.setCenter(tabla);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();    
  }
}

class Person {
    private BooleanProperty aceptado;

    public Person() {
      this.aceptado = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
    }
    public boolean isAceptado() {
      return aceptado.get();
    }
    public void setAceptado(boolean checked) {
      this.aceptado.set(checked);
    }
    public BooleanProperty propiedadAceptado() {
      return aceptado;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto:

```
 tuCheckBox.selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
     public void changed(ObservableValue ov,Boolean old_val,Booleannew_val) {
        System.out.println(new_val);
     }
   });
```

Comment: El problema es que el CheckBox está dentro de la celda y es controlado de forma automática y no sé como acceder a el. Se encuentra en 'cell'

Comment: Antes de agregar el CheckBox a la lista que te almacena los datos en la tabla le asignas este listener.